# Why are parts or even entire islands for the UV map not colored when baking texture?

Tags: uv, texture-baking

[Added files for reproducing the issue at the end, thanks for the feedback, Nathan]
I imported a received trailer model from .fbx and used smart UV project to get the UV layout. I then added a texture image node for each material, played with the UV resolution and bake settings to arrive at the currently best result shown in the image below. 
[image: Texture map] 
The problem is this, several UV islands remain partially black or even completely black, illustrated in the close-up below. 
[image: Close-up of the problem] 
This results in black spots for the textured model, like here. 
[image: Black spots in the textured model] 
When importing the model from .fbx, you can see that the model has various materials and some are double. Also, not every material is assigned to the right model part. Therefore, I've reassigned some colors right after importing the .fbx. So I tried to reproduce the issue by baking immediately after importing the model without making changes for the assigned materials and got the same result. 
I am new to Blender and I would like to know why this problem occurs and what I can do to avoid it. For reproducing the results, here are links to dropbox for the [blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/j02uwpzqrvtrjpa/model.blend?dl=0) and the [.fbx file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/teq08chbz1rrzqo/trailer_Dezeure_with_sides.fbx?dl=0).

Comment: What were the materials, and what was the bake type?  To answer this, people would need more info, and the best way to provide that info-- since you don't yet know what the relevant factors are-- is to link a .blend file.

Comment: I can't find the geometry in your last pic, or I'd inspect that carefully.  Otherwise, look at your second pic: the faces are smaller than the image pixels!  You simply don't have the image resolution to even see these faces on your image.  Also, check out and fix your normals.